# Run Python as root on boot issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

Usual apologies in advance if this is asked already, but I've spent the past few hours trying previous answers so I'm lost.

I have the following python script, running on a pi zero to detect RFID Cards and act as a HID Keyboard to type my password. It's not secure, I know, but it works perfectly.

It works when I SSH into the pi separately and launch the script. I'm trying to get it to launch at boot, not working too well. I've tried bashrc, init.d and any other ways I've found in my endeavors, so any other help would be greatly appreciated.

I've also tried screen through a bash script in concern that an active shell would be required for my script, no avail.

Here's my script:

```py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import MFRC522
import signal
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
continue_reading = True

NULL_CHAR = chr(0)
def writetofile(scr):
    f = open("logs.txt", "a")
    tim = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if scr == "error":
        f.write("Got error at ")
        f.write(tim)
        f.write("\r\n")
    else:
        f.write("Got Success with ")
        f.write(scr)
        f.write(" at ")
        f.write(tim)
        f.write("\r\n")

# function to send the data
def write_report(report):
    with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        fd.write(report.encode())
def login():
    ##writes my password, commands removed for stack :)


def uidToString(uid):
    mystring = ""
    for i in uid:
        mystring = format(i, '02X') + mystring
    return mystring


def end_read(signal, frame):
    global continue_reading
    print("Ctrl+C captured, ending read.")
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)


MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()


while continue_reading:

    # Scan for cards
    (status, TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)

    # If a card is found
    if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
        print ("Card detected")
                # Get the UID of the card
        (status, uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_SelectTagSN()
        # If we have the UID, continue
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            carduid = uidToString(uid)
            if carduid == '75AC5685':
                print("KeyRing")
                writetofile("Keyring")
                login()
            elif carduid == 'D539F1FD':
                print("Keycard")
                writetofile("Keycard")
                login()
            print("Card read UID: %s" % carduid)
        else:
            print("Authentication error")
            writetofile("error")
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you get any logs from when it is supposed to run? Do you know if it starts but crashes, or if it never starts?

Comment: When you try to launch it at startup, do you call it with `python script.py` or `/usr/bin/python script.py`?

Comment: @lxop I don't get any logs, I do know it must start with root and AFAIK have an active process... not sure why, might be something to do with SPI.

Comment: @lxop ````python script.py```

Comment: Try specifying the full path to python - there could be issues with PATH not being set up as you expect during startup

Comment: @lxop I’ll try this soon and be back, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lxop for his help, this wasn't my problem though.

Sorry for the wasted post, my mistake was I used the ~ directory in referencing the file obviously without being logged in. Everything works fine now. Thanks though!